# Overrided Multi Select BooleanField request response django

Tags: python, django, frontend

The information are here:

1. This is print(request.POST) in views.py

> <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['token'], 'agree_2': ['19', '22'], 'submit_multiple': ['']}>

2. My views.py
   return JsonResponse(request.POST)

> {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "token", "agree_2": "22", "submit_multiple": ""}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teklL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkfeG.png)

What i want to do is take post id to be value in boolean field and I want to take all

> "agree_2":["19","22"]

This is my views.py files

```
def index(request):
AVM_Form = AVMForm()
post = PostAVM.objects.all()
context = {
    'form':AVM_Form,
    'post':post,
}
if request.method=='POST':
    if 'submit_single' in request.POST:
        submitPost(request)        
        return HttpResponseRedirect('result/')
    elif 'submit_multiple' in request.POST:
        dump = request.POST
        print(dump)
        return JsonResponse(dump)
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Could anyone help me? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this.

I needed to do this to get all the list:

```
dump.getlist('agree_2')
```